# dynamic variables from array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I store the field names within an array, in hopes to dynamically create the variables.

I receive a illegal offset type error for the if and else, these two lines:

```
$data[$tmp_field] = $tmp_field[$id];

$data[$tmp_field] = 0;
```

I checked the post data and it is posting with the appropriate data, but I am not sure what the problem is.

$student_id stores all the students ids., for example: `$student_id = array(8,9,11,23,30,42,55);`

```
function updateStudentInfo() {
  $student_id = $this->input->post('student_id');
  $internet_student = $this->input->post('internet_student');
  $dismissed = $this->input->post('dismissed');
  $non_matriculated_student = $this->input->post('non_matriculated_student');
  $felony = $this->input->post('felony');
  $probation = $this->input->post('probation');
  $h_number = $this->input->post('h_number');
  $office_direct_to = $this->input->post('office_direct_to');
  $holds = $this->input->post('holds');

  $fields = array('internet_student', 'non_matriculated_student', 'h_number', 'felony', 'probation', 'dismissed');

  foreach($student_id as $id):
    $data = array();

    foreach($fields as $field_name):
      $tmp_field = ${$field_name};

      if(empty($tmp_field[$id])) {
        $data[$tmp_field] = 0;
      } else { 
        $data[$tmp_field] = $tmp_field[$id];
      }
    endforeach;

    print '<pre style="color:#fff;">';
    print_r($data);
    print '</pre>';

  endforeach;
}
```

This is the array format I desire:

```
Array
(
    [internet_student] => 1
    [non_matriculated_student] => 1
    [h_number] => 0
    [felony] => 0
    [probation] => 1
    [dismissed] => 0
)
```

Added screenshot to give you a visual of the form the data is being posted from

[image]

Comment: What happens when you use $data[$field_name] instead of $data[$tmp_field]? You are trying to set key as a array, which could give an error.

Comment: I'd go down the route of $student=array_merge(array('internet_student'=>0, 'non_matriculated_student'=>0, 'h_number'=>0, 'felony'=>0, 'probation'=>0, 'dismissed'=>0), $student);  this will create an array of 0 values and over-right any existing values over the top of it

Comment: @Waygood could you submit your answer with that example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($student_id as $id):
    $data = array();

    foreach($fields as $field_name):
      $tmp_field = ${$field_name};

      if(empty($tmp_field[$id])) {
        $data[$field_name] = 0;
      } else { 
        $data[$field_name] = $tmp_field[$id];
      }
    endforeach;

    print '<pre style="color:#fff;">';
    print_r($data);
    print '</pre>';

  endforeach;
```

Comment: That looks like it did the trick. I had $data[$tmp_field] = $tmp_field[$id]; wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that all these fields are arrays, as otherwise you wouldn't need any loops.

```
function updateStudentInfo()
{
    $student_id                 = $this->input->post('student_id');
    $internet_student           = $this->input->post('internet_student');
    $dismissed              = $this->input->post('dismissed');
    $non_matriculated_student   = $this->input->post('non_matriculated_student');
    $felony                     = $this->input->post('felony');
    $probation              = $this->input->post('probation');
    $h_number                   = $this->input->post('h_number');
    $office_direct_to           = $this->input->post('office_direct_to');
    $holds                  = $this->input->post('holds');

    $fields = array('internet_student', 'non_matriculated_student', 'h_number', 'felony', 'probation', 'dismissed');

    $student_count  = count($student_id);
    foreach($student_id as $id)
    {
        $data   = array();
        foreach($fields as $field)
        {
            if(array_key_exists($id, $$field))
                $data[$field]   = ${$field}[$id];
        }
    }
}
```

You are trying to use the student id as an array key for the other fields but the HTML form is just a standard indexed array, not keyed to any student data.

Comment: The $student_id stores an array of student's ID's, so I use the id's in there to pull the appropriate data from each array. For example, $student_id = array(8, 9, 11, 21, 30, 43);

Comment: @Brad are the other fields (h_number, holds, etc) coming from a HTML form?  If so then they aren't keyed to the student ids

Comment: yes, they are keyed into the $student_id id's. In the view, I have field names like this: h_number[$s->id], same for holds[$s->id][], dismissed[$s->id]

Comment: @Brad oh, I thought this was direct from the submitted form.  I've tweaked the loop to use the student id